# Why does the textblock environment not obey the overlay settings when used within \onlyenv?

Tags: beamer, overlays, textpos

I have an image that I want to explain with floating texts, arrows, and circles. To do so, I thought about creating a `textblock` environment (to put text) and a picture environment (to put the arrows and ovals) nested into an `onlyenv` environment. Into a unique frame, I could put as many `\onlyenv` as I want to move the texts, arrows, and circles around the picture.

Expected behaviour: The `textblock` and the picture environment should appear only in the layers defined by the `onlyenv` environment.

Observed behaviour: Only the picture environment obeyed the `\onlyenv` setting. The `textblock` environment appears in all layers.

For instance, consider the following `LaTeX` file

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
% graphical config
\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm} % set default length
\thicklines

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
    \begin{onlyenv}<+>
        \begin{figure}
            \vspace{3cm}
            % \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{picture}(1,1)
            \put(6.5,5){\vector(1,-1){0.85}}
            \put(8.7,3.1){\oval(3.1,2.5)}
            \put(8.7,3.1){\thebeamerpauses}
        \end{picture}
        
        \begin{textblock}{10}(1,3)
            \lipsum[66] \thebeamerpauses
        \end{textblock}
    \end{onlyenv}
    
    \begin{onlyenv}<+>
        \begin{figure}
            \vspace{3cm}
            % \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-b}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{picture}(1,1)
            \put(6.5,1){\vector(1,-1){0.85}}
            \put(6.7,2.1){\oval(3.1,2.5)}
            \put(6.7,2.1){\thebeamerpauses}
        \end{picture}
        
        \begin{textblock}{10}(1,9)
            \lipsum[75] \thebeamerpauses
        \end{textblock}
    \end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This yields

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textpos` [overlay] option uses a fairly simple-minded mechanism to control the order in which elements are added to the output page.  The `beamer` environment does quite sophisticated things to control positioning on the page, and these are unlikely to interact well with the [overlay] mode.

Instead, use `textpos` without options: `\usepackage{textpos}`.  In this mode, the `{textblock}` environment simply adds a zero size box to the page, and the offset `(hpos,ypos)` is relative to the location of this box on the page.  Specifically, in this mode `textpos` does nothing clever about adding material, so can't confuse, or be confused by, beamer.

If you move the `{textblock}` to the beginning of the `{frame}`, which will have a consistent, predictable position, and write

```
\begin{onlyenv}<+>
    \begin{textblock}{10}(0,0)
        \lipsum[66] \thebeamerpauses
    \end{textblock}
    \begin{figure}
    ....
```

then you might get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: It worked out! Thank you! I have some questions though... Why does the `textblock` env have a predictable position only if it is the very first block inside the `\onlyenv`?

Comment: "Specifically, in this mode textpos does nothing clever about adding material". What do you exactly mean by "material"?

Comment: The `textblock` environment simply adds a zero-size box at the location in the document where it appears.  If it's the first thing in the beamer frame, it therefore always adds that block at the beginning of the frame; if it appeared after other text (and by ‘material’ I simply meant text or other boxes), the textblock would appear there. Or, put another way, the offset in the `textblock` (hpos,ypos) argument is relative to the block's ‘natural’ position, but in [absolute] mode, it's relative to the top-left corner of the page (but it does that in a slightly tricky way, which confuses beamer).

Comment: (so ‘predictable’ is perhaps not the correct word: independent of other material in the textblock would be a better way of putting it)